# What is the error in my “filter_complex” settings?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am a beginner. I have something to ask. I used this:

```
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[d][v1];[d][v1]overlay=enable='between(t,495.8,509)'[v2];[d][v2 ]overlay=enable='between(t,517.5,561.8)'[v3]" -map'[v3]'
```

And I am getting this error message:

> Error msg : Stream specifier'd' in filtergraph description [1:v][0:v]scale2ref[d][v1];[d][v1]overlay=enable='between(t,495.8,509)'[v2]; [d][v2]overlay=enable='between(t,517.5,561.8)'[v3] matches no streams.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The error is effectively `[v3] matches no streams.` which means your input doesn't have a `v3` stream. I you are copying and pasting this from another source you need to adapt that stuff to match your video streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [d] twice, split it before reuse:

```
ffmpeg -i "input 1.mp4" -i "test1.mkv" -filter_complex "
[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[1v][0v];
[1v]split[1v0][1v1];
[0v][1v0]overlay=enable='between(t,3,6)'[over1];
[over1][1v1]overlay=enable='between(t,9,12)'[over2]
" -map [over2] -y output.mp4
```

[edited] if 5 split, thanks to llogan:

```
ffmpeg -i "input 1.mp4" -i "test01.mkv" -filter_complex "
[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[1v][0v];
[1v]split=5[1v1][1v2][1v3][1v4][1v5];
[0v][1v1]overlay=enable='between(t,2,4)'[over1];
[over1][1v2]overlay=enable='between(t,6,8)'[over2];
[over2][1v3]overlay=enable='between(t,10,12)'[over3];
[over3][1v4]overlay=enable='between(t,14,16)'[over4];
[over4][1v5]overlay=enable='between(t,18,20)'[over5]
" -map [over5] -y output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you. In the above question, assuming that it is up to v5, can we increase the over3,4 in the back? I'm sorry I keep asking questions.

Comment: It's a chain. Yeah, you can increase chain to any size you want.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов You can use one instance of [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split): `[1v]split=outputs=5[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]`